# Default or custom error page? - WebConfig custom error defaultRedirect

Tags: asp.net, configuration, custom-error-pages, system.web

Preparing for an exam, **Do you get the default error page if you don't specify the error code inside customError?**

I thought since you have defaultRedirect set, all errors regardless if they are accounted for specifically get sent to the defaultRedirect page. However the practice questions I've seen say the opposite. I looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.customerror?view=netframework-4.7.2) and I can only see it say it refers to the default if the custom page doesn't exist

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.htm">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/CustomError.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

*Original Question*

*When a 400-level error occurs, the ASP.NET default error page displays. [True / False]*

I believe it's false, answers say it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you get the default error page if you don't specify the error code
>   inside customError?

Yes. If you do not specify the error code inside customError, the default error page will be used. if you specify the error code inside customError, the specified page will be used. Of course, customError only applies to elements handled by ASP.NET, so it is possible you can get the IIS error page instead of anything listed in your web.config file.

From the documentation you linked to,

> When you define a custom error, ASP.NET assigns to it the standard
>   error normally issued by the underlying service, such as IIS. **For
>   instance, if you define a custom error for the status code 404,
>   ASP.NET will issue it anytime you refer to a non-existing .aspx page.**
>   The custom errors are only issued for those elements handled by
>   ASP.NET. For instance, **if you refer to a non-existing .htm page, IIS
>   issues the standard 404 error.**

To answer the specific question you provided,

> When a 400-level error occurs, the ASP.NET default error page
>   displays. [True / False]

This is True, since there are no pages specified for 400-level error in the web.config, thus the default error page is used. This assumes the error occurs within the ASP.NET application.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What is the point of "defaultRedirect="Error.htm"" if unspecified errors use the iis default error? Are you able to declare multiple errors codes and not specify the redirect portion, so they'll all go to your custom defaultRedirect?

Comment: The defaultRedirect property is the default error page that the ASP.NET application will use if the error code is not given a specific page and the error is handled by ASP.NET. You would only see the IIS error page if the error is not handled by ASP.NET. There is an example in the documentation you linked.  I don't see any documentation on what happens if you remove defaultRedirect, but you could try it and see. Working through this would help you understand more than anything. If my answer helped, please consider giving me an upvote and marking it as best answer. Thanks!